# azure terraform attaching azure file share to windows machine

Tags: azure, azure-storage, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-files

**Problem statement**
I am in the process to create an Azure VM cluster of windows os. till now I can create an Azure file share. and azure windows cluster. I want to attach file share created to each VM in my cluster. unable to find reference how to add same on windows VM.

**code for this**

```
resource "azurerm_storage_account" "main" {
  name                     = "stor${var.environment}${var.cost_centre}${var.project}"
  location                     = "${azurerm_resource_group.main.location}"
  resource_group_name          = "${azurerm_resource_group.main.name}"
  account_tier             = "${var.storage_account_tier}"
  account_replication_type = "${var.storage_replication_type}"
}


resource "azurerm_storage_share" "main" {
  name = "storageshare${var.environment}${var.cost_centre}${var.project}"

  resource_group_name  = "${azurerm_resource_group.main.name}"
  storage_account_name = "${azurerm_storage_account.main.name}"

  quota = "${var.storage_share_quota}"
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "vm" {
  name                  = "vm-${var.location_id}-${var.environment}-${var.cost_centre}-${var.project}-${var.seq_id}-${count.index}"
  location              = "${azurerm_resource_group.main.location}"
  resource_group_name   = "${azurerm_resource_group.main.name}"
  availability_set_id   = "${azurerm_availability_set.main.id}"
  vm_size               = "${var.vm_size}"
  network_interface_ids = ["${element(azurerm_network_interface.main.*.id, count.index)}"]
  count                 = "${var.vm_count}"

  storage_image_reference {
    publisher = "${var.image_publisher}"
    offer     = "${var.image_offer}"
    sku       = "${var.image_sku}"
    version   = "${var.image_version}"
  }

  storage_os_disk {
    name          = "osdisk${count.index}"
    create_option = "FromImage"
  }

  os_profile {
    computer_name  = "${var.vm_name}-${count.index}"
    admin_username = "${var.admin_username}"
    admin_password = "${var.admin_password}"
  }

  os_profile_windows_config {}

  depends_on = ["azurerm_network_interface.main"]

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Azure doesnt offer anything like that, so uou cannot do that natively, you need to create a script and run that script on the vm use script extension\dsc extension or if terraform supports that - with terraform.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/custom-script-linux